# php mysql field names as <th>?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a mysql query and have the results displaying in a table but would like to put the field or column names from the mysql table as the table headers. I would like to do this with multiple php files but one is a little complicated because it uses a for loop to display records tied to each other by a common field. Here is the easy result table

```
echo "<table border='1' width='85%' cellpadding='5' align='center'>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 echo "\t<tr align='center'>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
echo "\t\t<td align='center'>$col_value</td>\n";
}

 echo "<td align='center'><img src=./images/$col_value border='3' ></td>";

 echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

I'm not sure where to but the  tag and how to get the mysql column names. I tried something with mysql_field_names and no luck. Here is the other table with the for loop.

```
$last_pattern = null;
echo "<table border='1' width='80%' cellpadding='5' align='center'>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 $col_count = count($line) - 1; // Subtract 1 because image isn't in a column
if ($line['PatternName'] !== $last_pattern) {
if ($last_pattern !== null) {
  echo "<td><tr align='center'>\n";
}
echo "<tr align='center'>\n  ";
foreach ($line as $col_name => $col_value) {
  switch ($col_name) {
  case 'YarnImage':
    break;
  case 'PatternImage':
    echo "<td><image src='images/$col_value' /></td>";
    break;
  default:
    echo "<td>$col_value</td>";
  }
}
$last_pattern = $line['PatternName'];
echo "</tr>\n  <tr align='center'><td colspan='$col_count'>\n";
}
$yarn_image = $line['YarnImage'];
echo "<img src='images/$yarn_image' width='150' height='150' border='3'/>\n";
}
if ($last_image !== null) {
echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: thanks for the advice, but this is just for a class project and its just a learning experience. this page is only on the college server.

Comment: It appears you do know the field names... is there any reason that you can't just manually insert them before looping through the results?

Comment: @user1883671, all the more reason to learn the new, correct way of working with databases in PHP, instead of continuing practices that have been out of date since 2004.

Answer (score 2):

After you have fetched the first row as an associative array, you can get the column names with `array_keys($line)`.

If you decide to stop using the deprecated ext/mysql functions, and switch to ext/mysqli or pdo_mysql, you can enjoy nice functions like [mysqli_stmt::result_metadata()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php) or [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<th>` loop above you `foreach ($line as $col_name => $col_value)` loop

```
$col_number = 1; // add a counter
foreach ($line as $col_names => $col_values) {
    if ($col_number <= $col_count){  // check if counter is >= to $col_count
    echo "<th>$col_names</th>";}
    $col_number++;}  // increase counter by 1
foreach ($line as $col_name => $col_value) {
... //rest of you code
```

Also, on the 7th line of your code, you have an invalid table element -

```
  echo "<td><tr align='center'>\n";
```

Comment: I used the above $col_names => $col_values and it worked perfectly, is there an easy way to cutoff the last column name since its for the row underneath it and makes an empty column.

Comment: It can be done using a simple counter, and checking it against your `$col_count` that you set just before as it is the count of columns minus the image. I have updated my answer with a sample counter.

Comment: I tried this counter and keep breaking the page. I've tried rearranging the {} earlier on in the code I used $col_count = count($line) -1, is there a way i can do that with the variable $col_names? I've tried different combos of that string and it's still not working

Comment: I just noticed that I left of the `;` at the end of `$col_number++;`.  This could be the cause of the page failing. I have corrected it in my example.